# Vertical scroll bar appearing even when height is not set

Tags: html, css, overflow

If you save the file below in html format, you will that a vertical scroll bar appears. Since the height for

```
<div class="tabData" id="tab3data" style="visibility: visible;">
```

is not set, shouldn't it automatically expand to fit all the contents?

```
<html dir="ltr" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .tabData
        {
            width: 100%;
            background-color: Yellow;
            overflow: auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="tabData">
        <div style="height: 390px; background-color: Green;">
            <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br />
            </div> 
        Hello
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Try it in Firefox using the firebug tool

Comment: other than recommending to check for `overflow: auto` being set ( set to `overflow: visible` if so ), I don't think anyone can help without seeing some code

Comment: Or use the developer tools in IE or Chrome by pressing F12. This will enable you to debug on the fly

Comment: Firefox's inspector is the best for inspecting CSS in my experience. I even prefer it over firebug.

Comment: You can always setup a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) if you dont want to paste your code

Comment: Check parents' heights recursively until you find the one whose height is set

Comment: Do you really need all of that code?

Comment: you haven't give us any code

Comment: fixed it, code added.

Comment: It looks correct http://jsfiddle.net/4kFD7/ what else you want ?

Comment: I am not able to understand why the scroll bar is appearing. The outer container has no height set on it. SHouldn't it just expand instead of showing a scrollbar? How does it know at what height to start showing the scroll bar?

Comment: @Foo I posted an explanation about why the scroll bar appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a parent container `div.tabData` whose height is determined by the total heights of the child elements, of which there are two, the inner `<div>` and the anonymous block that contains the word "Hello".

The inner `div` has a height of 390px and the "Hello" line takes up about 1.5em.  Therefore, the parent element with the yellow background is just big enough to enclose the 390px inner div and the one line of text.

If you add enough content to the inner div, the text will eventually flow outside of the inner div that has the green background.  This is how browsers work by default, they try to make the text visible no matter what.

However, as far as the parent element is concerned, it has the right height based on 390px + height-of-1-line-of-text.  Browsers will not recalculate a block element's height when text overflows out of a fixed height child element.

If you continue to add more text to the inner div, it starts to flow over any text in the parent element, and eventually, it will overflow the parent container and cause a vertical scroll bar to appear since you set `overflow: auto` on the parent element.

On the other hand, is you had not fixed the height of the inner div, you would get the expected behavior, the inner div expands to contain all its content, and the parent div expands to enclose both the inner div and the one line of text.

**Example**

If you try the following fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/s3bnJ/, and adjust the horizontal width, you can see the text from the inner div flow out of the inner div and into the parent div, and eventually, you will see the scroll bar appear.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already aware of browser-based developer tools I will assume that you have already inspected the div in question. I assume that upon inspection you viewed the styles that were defined explicitly for that div. I also assume that you also checked for inherited styles that may have been affecting that div.

Could it be that the div in question is not the element that has the scrollbar? By this I mean, perhaps you have another element wrapped around the div that is producing a scrollbar. Or perhaps there is an element inside the div that is producing the scrollbar. In other words, the problem may not actually be the div in question.

As has already been mentioned, this will be hard for others to help with unless we see the actual code. If you just want to get rid of the scrollbar, you can do as @Adriano suggests and set the overflow to none.

Answer (score 0):

You have an inline `height: 390px;` on the inner `div` of `.tabData` and its content doesn't fit in that height, `overflow: auto;` on the parent (`tabData`) in your css makes it to render vertical scroll for that reason.

Here is a fix for you if you want to keep your current structure:

**Fix**: http://jsfiddle.net/QvMfJ/

Comment: Why is scroll not appearing on just the green area? Why is it appearing on the parent (yellow area), where no height is set?

Comment: Because `overflow:auto;` is set on the parent. I added a fix for you if you want to keep your current structure.

Comment: I tried your fix in the browser, sorry it doesn't seem to be working :(

Comment: Make sure to remove the inline styling you originally had on the inner Green div, not just editing your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Try using min-height if you want it to expand to fill the necessary space, or overflow:hidden if you don't want to grow it, or have scroll bars.

Answer (score -1):

set the div with overflow:none;

UPDATING:

Depending how the content of the div is been shown you can try this: overflow:hidden;. For example, if the scroll bar appears but you don't have to use it to see the content the 'hidden' argument will fix the problem.

Comment: There is no such thing as `overflow: none`.

Comment: Sorry guys, it was a type mistake. I meant overflow:hidden; to solve the problem.